# ubuntu starts to be slow

Tags: lubuntu, firefox, vlc, fan, boinc

I have ubuntu 10.04 since 2010..almost no problems, maybe missing some programs/features from windows but no regrets..
but recently it starts to slow down, to even stop sometimes, and i need to restart it. sometimes i need to take off the battery to restart.
the problem is that it gets too hot sometimes, usually when I watch some video already in my laptop or when I use mozilla firefox (but also with other web browers; especially when i check facebook, emails, or using youtube)
I need to add that I use boinc manager all the time to help science, so maybe it makes it hotter
I have enough space in both partitions: programs and data (respectively 5gb for programs and 30 for personal data)
I have some hypothesis: 
1_the computer is too old (3 years) and maybe the fan inside is not working properly anymore
2_1Gb ram is not enough anymore to support ubuntu 10.04, I mean after all the updates and the programs I downloaded in 3/4 years, especially when running firefox and video players
3_boinc makes it too hot
4_simply firefox is too heavy to run properly
5_simply vlc (or other media players) is too heavy to run properly (or maybe the videos I try to watch are too much high definitions)

I need to say that now it's working a little better (but not too much), but I dont know if it's because the weather here it's a little bit cooler now, or because I use other web browers for different things, or because boinc now runs at lower % of usage...
So...after this long exposition of facts, what I want to know is:
what do you think should I do to makes my computer working well again?
I mean: I do not like spend money for a new computer or for a new fan if it's not absolutely necessary.
at the moment I'm thinking about other options like using a different OS, like Lubuntu or puppylinux, because I read they are lighter. but I think if I install the same programs on Lubuntu (for example) I will have the same problem, right? because it will become of the same weight, or am I thinking in the wrong way?
and the case I install one of them (puppylinux or lubuntu), will I be able to use the same programs I use to use? especially firefox, boinc manager, vlc player, and others from ubuntu?

Comment: You can usually power off your computer by holding the power button for 4–10 seconds – no need to take out the battery.

Comment: Another suggestion: Upgrade the OS since 10.04 is no longer supported and thus is lacking in both security and stability updates. Other than that, I agree with cleaning it out. I run BOINC myself and it can definitely heat up the computer on its own. You could try lowering its impact on the PC by going to Tools->Computing Preferences and then unchecking the box that says "While the computer is in use" and decreasing the value of "Use at most [   ]% of CPU time"

Answer (score 1):

## Short answer

Sounds like an overheating problem.

## Long answer

Video decoding (without proper hardware acceleration support) and scientific computing are very demanding tasks and will consume more electric power and consequently heat up your computer. If too much dust assembles over time, the internal fans aren't able to keep enough cool air streaming through the computer case to keep the hardware temperature at acceptable levels. This can cause performance throttling (to decrease power consumption and heat exhaustion) or (most often temporary) random hardware failures that result in system freezes or crashes.

## Solution

Try to clean out the dust from your computer.